# Leaflet - Add overlapping circles to the flyer map with uniform transparency -JS

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geometry

everyone,
I would like to make a map with a starting point and a different radius all around. 
Each radius corresponds to a zone and a price.
Currently my circles all have an oppacity so that the map is visible underneath.

But putting circles on top of each other and the colors and their opacity too, I'd like them all to have a uniform oppacity.
I had found someone with the same concern but it's R.
link: [Add overlapping circles to leaflet map with homogeneous transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54913931/add-overlapping-circles-to-leaflet-map-with-homogeneous-transparency)
[image]
[image]

Quelqu'un pourrait-il m'aider ?
Here a picture of my problem:
[image]

```
var latitude = 48.806412;
var longitude = 3.074664;

var myMap = L.map('map').setView([latitude, longitude], 13);
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 18,
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
}).addTo(myMap);

var latLong = [{
  "lat": latitude,
  "lng": longitude,
}];

var latLong2 = [{
  "lat": latitude,
  "lng": longitude,
}];

var latLong3 = [{
  "lat": latitude,
  "lng": longitude,
}];

var latLong4 = [{
  "lat": latitude,
  "lng": longitude,
}];

var latLong5 = [{
  "lat": latitude,
  "lng": longitude,
}];

var latLong6 = [{
  "lat": latitude,
  "lng": longitude,
}];

var latLong7 = [{
  "lat": latitude,
  "lng": longitude,
}];





var circle = L.circle(latLong[0], {
  color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
  fillColor: 'rgba(153, 204, 51, 0.2)',
  fillOpacity: 1,
  radius: 5000,
  weight: 1,
}).addTo(myMap);

var isClicked = false;
circle.on('click', function() {
  isClicked = !isClicked;
  if (isClicked) {
    document.querySelector('.z1').style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(153, 204, 51, 0.5)';
    document.querySelector('.z1').style.border = '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.z1').style.backgroundColor = '';
    document.querySelector('.z1').style.border = '';
  }
});

circle.on('mouseover', function() {
  document.querySelector('.z1').classList.add('highlight');
});
circle.on('mouseout', function() {
  if (!isClicked) {
    document.querySelector('.z1').classList.remove('highlight');
  }
});







var circle2 = L.circle(latLong2[0], {
  color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
  fillColor: 'rgba(153, 204, 51, 0.2)',
  fillOpacity: 1,
  radius: 10000,
  weight: 1,
}).addTo(myMap);

var isClicked2 = false;
circle2.on('click', function() {
  isClicked2 = !isClicked2;
  if (isClicked2) {
    document.querySelector('.z2').style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(153, 204, 51, 0.5)';
    document.querySelector('.z2').style.border = '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.z2').style.backgroundColor = '';
    document.querySelector('.z2').style.border = '';
  }
});

circle2.on('mouseover', function() {
  document.querySelector('.z2').classList.add('highlight');
});
circle2.on('mouseout', function() {
  document.querySelector('.z2').classList.remove('highlight');
});







var circle3 = L.circle(latLong3[0], {
  color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
  fillColor: 'rgba(153, 204, 51, 0.2)',
  fillOpacity: 1,
  radius: 15000,
  weight: 1,
}).addTo(myMap);

var isClicked3 = false;
circle3.on('click', function() {
  isClicked3 = !isClicked3;
  if (isClicked3) {
    document.querySelector('.z3').style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(153, 204, 51, 0.5)';
    document.querySelector('.z2').style.border = '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.z3').style.backgroundColor = '';
    document.querySelector('.z3').style.border = '';
  }
});

circle3.on('mouseover', function() {
  document.querySelector('.z3').classList.add('highlight');
});
circle3.on('mouseout', function() {
  document.querySelector('.z3').classList.remove('highlight');
});








var circle4 = L.circle(latLong4[0], {
  color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
  fillColor: 'rgba(153, 204, 51, 0.2)',
  fillOpacity: 1,
  radius: 25000,
  weight: 1,
}).addTo(myMap);

var isClicked4 = false;
circle4.on('click', function() {
  isClicked4 = !isClicked4;
  if (isClicked4) {
    document.querySelector('.z4').style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(153, 204, 51, 0.5)';
    document.querySelector('.z4').style.border = '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.z4').style.backgroundColor = '';
    document.querySelector('.z4').style.border = '';
  }
});

circle4.on('mouseover', function() {
  document.querySelector('.z4').classList.add('highlight');
});
circle4.on('mouseout', function() {
  document.querySelector('.z4').classList.remove('highlight');
});










var circle5 = L.circle(latLong5[0], {
  color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
  fillColor: 'rgba(153, 204, 51, 0.2)',
  fillOpacity: 1,
  radius: 35000,
  weight: 1,
}).addTo(myMap);

var isClicked5 = false;
circle5.on('click', function() {
  isClicked5 = !isClicked5;
  if (isClicked5) {
    document.querySelector('.z5').style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(153, 204, 51, 0.5)';
    document.querySelector('.z5').style.border = '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.z5').style.backgroundColor = '';
    document.querySelector('.z5').style.border = '';
  }
});

circle5.on('mouseover', function() {
  document.querySelector('.z5').classList.add('highlight');
});
circle5.on('mouseout', function() {
  document.querySelector('.z5').classList.remove('highlight');
});








var circle6 = L.circle(latLong6[0], {
  color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
  fillColor: 'rgba(153, 204, 51, 0.2)',
  fillOpacity: 1,
  radius: 50000,
  weight: 1,
}).addTo(myMap);

var isClicked6 = false;
circle6.on('click', function() {
  isClicked6 = !isClicked6;
  if (isClicked6) {
    document.querySelector('.z6').style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(153, 204, 51, 0.5)';
    document.querySelector('.z6').style.border = '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.z6').style.backgroundColor = '';
    document.querySelector('.z6').style.border = '';
  }
});

circle6.on('mouseover', function() {
  document.querySelector('.z6').classList.add('highlight');
});
circle6.on('mouseout', function() {
  document.querySelector('.z6').classList.remove('highlight');
});










var circle7 = L.circle(latLong6[0], {
  color: 'none',
  fillColor: 'rgba(153, 204, 51, 0.0)',
  fillOpacity: 1,
  radius: 100000000000000,
  weight: 1,
}).addTo(myMap);

var isClicked7 = false;
circle7.on('click', function() {
  isClicked7 = !isClicked7;
  if (isClicked7) {
    document.querySelector('.z7').style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(153, 204, 51, 0.5)';
    document.querySelector('.z7').style.border = '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.z7').style.backgroundColor = '';
    document.querySelector('.z7').style.border = '';
  }
});

circle7.on('mouseover', function() {
  document.querySelector('.z7').classList.add('highlight');
});
circle7.on('mouseout', function() {
  document.querySelector('.z7').classList.remove('highlight');
});

circle6.bringToFront();
circle5.bringToFront();
circle4.bringToFront();
circle3.bringToFront();
circle2.bringToFront();
circle.bringToFront();

myMap.panTo([latitude, longitude]);
```

Could someone help me?